# Start plotting at y-axis in R

Tags: r, plot, border

I'm drawing a ROC curve and R is putting to much space between the curve and the plot border. I want values at x = 0 to touch the y-axis and points at y = 1 to touch the upper border of the plot.

This image shows exactly how I want it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Roccurves.png

Anyone got any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For base graphics, use the axis style parameters, `xaxs` and `yaxs`, to constrain the plotting limits to the of the data.

```
dfr <- data.frame(x = 0:1, y = 0:1)
par(xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
with(dfr, plot(x, y))
```

For lattice, you use the `xlim` and `ylim` parameters.

```
xyplot(y ~ x, dfr, xlim = range(dfr$x), ylim = range(dfr$y))
```

For ggplot2, use `coord_cartesian`.

```
ggplot(dfr, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = range(dfr$x), ylim = range(dfr$y))
```

Comment: Adding [xaxs = "i",yaxs = "i"] to the plot call fixed everything, thanks!